# ImageField upload_to in django 1.6 not displaying images to template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

In my django application, I have created a django model with an ImageField.

The problem is that the image itself is not getting rendered on the template. However, the image path is displayed on the template itself.

Also when I look in my media folder, I can see that the images that I uploaded are stored there.

My media root configuration in `settings.py` is as follows:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = ("D:/Work-Backup/LiClipse Workspace/vTryON_DJango_Integration/vTryON/templates/media" 

    )
```

My models.py is as follows

```
from django.db import models
```

class VTryON(models.Model):

```
modelId = models.CharField(max_length=100)
slug= models.SlugField(unique=True)   
image=models.ImageField(upload_to="images/framethumbs/", help_text="not more than 1MB", default ='D:/Work-Backup/LiClipse Workspace/vTryON_DJango_Integration/vTryON/templates/static/images/frame2.jpg')

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.modelId)
```

and my template is

```
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <title>vTryOn Attempt Using Django Framework</title>

</head>    
<body class="body">
      {{frame.image}}
</body>
</html>
```

The image path that is displayed on the template looks like this

```
images/framethumbs/fr_5.jpg
```

I have created a folder images/framethumbs under the MEDIA_ROOT url where all the images are stored. can it be a permission issue?

If so then, how and where do I give permissions?

I am using a Windows 7 PC. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with django well, but shouldn't the Windows paths be backslashed? For example: **D:\Work-Backup\LiClipse**... instead of **D:/Work-Backup/LiClipse**...

Comment: Well, I dont think that can be the issue since I have watched the tutorials and they use forward slash. also there are other entries in the settings.py which use forward slash and they seem to be working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have an entry in urls.py to server the static files, if not add this to urls.py file..

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
   (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
       'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Now to get the image you should use an image tag like this...

```
  <img src="{{ frame.image.url }}" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @adrita Can you please post the error which you are getting...?

Comment: I am not getting any error. The image path is displayed on the template where the image should be displayed.

Comment: to get the image you will have to use an image tag like this.`<img src="{{frame.image}}">` Can you please try and let me know if this works...!!!

Comment: Hey! it worked..! I wrote this line of code                          <td class="frameDiv"><img src="{{frame.image.url}}" width=200 height =100/></td>  ... Thanks a lot!!